# Jquery Calculation Multiple Price * Qty

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery to try and multiple  `price` * the `Qty`. What is the best way of doing this?

**I have try**

```
var qty = $('#Qty').val();
var price = $('#pricetag').text() * var qty;
```

But that didnt show anything.

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#button').click(function()
    {
        var qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var price = $('#pricetag').text();

        $('#sprice').text(price);


        $('#selected').slideDown();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `parseInt` is your friend http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp, also remove the `var` before `qty`

Comment: How will i add a euro sign to the out put because if i do it on the table the output of the price will override it

Comment: try `$('#sprice').text("&#8364;" + price);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var price = parseInt($('#pricetag').text(),10) * qty;
```

instead.

That parses your text into an integer – e.g. turning '10' (text) into 10 (a number).

Comment: I want to show a $ sign in the price output where will i add that please

Comment: var price = '$' + parseInt($('#pricetag').text(),10) * qty;

Comment: how come the `£` doesn't should even though i have add `&pound;`

Comment: You probably don't need to use &pound; – just a £ should work.

Comment: I used `£` but it came out as a `?`

Comment: You probably need to ensure your website is being sent with the right character encoding. Kinda out of scope for this question – look up how to send your website as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-declare your `qty` variable.

```
var qty = $('#Qty').val();
var price = parseInt($('#pricetag').text()) * qty;
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V5j4Q/) showing the basic principle.

**EDIT** Per your comment, to add a `$` before the price, just do this:

```
var price = '$' + parseInt($('#pricetag').text()) * qty;
```

Updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V5j4Q/1/) with the `$` added.

Answer (score 1):

You have to Parse the Values to an Integer to do calculations.

```
var price = parseInt($('#pricetag').text());
```

And dont write `... * var qty;` you have to let the "var" away here